# how to set logging interceptor using OkHttpClient with time out for retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

i basically want want use both of below features

// logging

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(logging)
                .build();
```

// time out

```
 OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(300,TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add it there:

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(logging)
                .connectTimeout(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(300,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use builder with both interceptor and timeouts.

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                        .addInterceptor(logging)
                        .connectTimeout(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .readTimeout(300,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .build();
```